# How to pivot data in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have data that looks much like this (3 columns of data), unfortunately I can't get it to display properly

```
NCR NO  LU_NAME           KEY_REF
100001  Project           PROJECT_ID=ID#^
100001  SupplierInfo      SUPPLIER_ID=UNIQUESUPPLIERNUMBER^
100001  PurchaseOrder     ORDER_NO=UNIQUEORDERNO^
100196  PurchaseReceipt   UNIQUE PURCHASE RECEIPT
100511  InventoryPart     CONTRACT=UNIQUECONTRACTNO
```

What I want is to have one record for each `NCR number` and a column of data for `Project`, `SupplierInfo`, etc, which contains the unique `Key_Ref`.   Let's say the table name is `OC`.   Can someone assist with the code to do this?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? Does it support pivoting? If so, take a look at that concept.

Answer (score 4):

This type of data transformation is called a *pivot*, some database products have a function that can do this for you.

If you are working in a database that does not have a pivot function, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select ncr_no,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'Project' then KEY_REF end) Project,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'SupplierInfo' then KEY_REF end) SupplierInfo,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'PurchaseOrder' then KEY_REF end) PurchaseOrder,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'PurchaseReceipt' then KEY_REF end) PurchaseReceipt,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'InventoryPart' then KEY_REF end) InventoryPart
from yourtable
group by ncr_no
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/419d9/1).

The above will work great with a known number or finite number of `LU_NAME` values, if you will have an unknown number then you will need to implement dynamic SQL but that code will vary depending on your database.

Comment: That works great. In the Project Field, I'm seeing something like PROJECT_ID=TheProjectID^ or PROJECT_ID=MyProjectID^.   I'd like to clean this up by removing PROJECT_ID= from the beginning and the ^ from the end.   How would I do that?

Comment: @BarbReinhardt You should post a new question with some sample data and then what you want the desired result to be.  When posting the new question include your database product because each database has different functions.