# Replacing values in fields

Tags: sql

Thanks for your help so far.   This is a continuation of a previous thread.

[How to pivot data in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417705/how-to-pivot-data-in-sql)

I what I want to do is replace the values in one of the resulting fields (let's say PROJECT_ID) to do something like this.    I'm hoping this is something SIMPLE.  But there's much more to this project.

```
select oc.ncr_no,
  max(case when OC.LU_NAME = 'Project' then OC.KEY_REF end) PROJECT_ID,
  max(case when OC.LU_NAME = 'SupplierInfo' then OC.KEY_REF end) SUPPLIER_ID,
  max(case when OC.LU_NAME = 'PurchaseOrder' then OC.KEY_REF end) ORDER_NO,
  max(case when OC.LU_NAME = 'PurchaseReceipt' then OC.KEY_REF end) PURCHASE_RECEIPT,
  max(case when OC.LU_NAME = 'InventoryPart' then OC.KEY_REF end) INVENTORY_PART,
  replace(PROJECT_ID,'PROJECT_ID=','') as PROJECT_ID
from OC
group by oc.ncr_no
```

I used this schema for the example  (pulled from SQL Fiddle).   Unfortunately I can't figure out how to save it.

```
CREATE TABLE OC 
(
  [NCR_NO] int, 
  [LU_NAME] varchar(15), 
  [KEY_REF] varchar(33)
);

INSERT INTO OC ([NCR_NO], [LU_NAME], [KEY_REF])
VALUES
    (100001, 'Project', 'PROJECT_ID=PROJECT1^'),
    (100001, 'SupplierInfo', 'SUPPLIER_ID=UNIQUESUPPLIERNUMBER^'),
    (100001, 'PurchaseOrder', 'ORDER_NO=UNIQUEORDERNO^'),
    (100196, 'PurchaseReceipt', 'UNIQUE PURCHASE RECEIPT'),
    (100511, 'InventoryPart', 'CONTRACT=UNIQUECONTRACTNO');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to remove everything before the `=` in each `KEY_REF`. If so, you can use:

```
select ncr_no,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'Project' then KEY_REF end) Project,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'SupplierInfo' then KEY_REF end) SupplierInfo,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'PurchaseOrder' then KEY_REF end) PurchaseOrder,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'PurchaseReceipt' then KEY_REF end) PurchaseReceipt,
  max(case when LU_NAME = 'InventoryPart' then KEY_REF end) InventoryPart
from
(
  select ncr_no, 
    LU_NAME, 
    substring(KEY_REF, charindex('=', key_ref)+1 , len(key_ref)) KEY_REF
  from yourtable
) src
group by ncr_no;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/419d9/18).

Note: this is the basic syntax that you can use but this could change depending on what database you are using.

Comment: I guess he wants to provide the information located on the right of the equal sign.
You can enrich your query by replacing KEY_REF with SUBSTR(KEY_REF,INSTR(KEY_REF,'='),LENGTH(KEY_REF))

Comment: @AHocevar It really depends on what database product they are using.  There are many different ways that this can be done, but it would be helpful if we knew what database.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the question, thinking he was using oracle